# Insufficient geocoding precision in Brazil

Tags: geocoding, here-api

I've been working with a logistics company and using Here services for Geocoding, Routing, and Telematics. We've been facing a couple of issues regarding the precision of the geocoding API when compared to Google results.

Here are some examples:

## 1) Returning wrong address even though the information is complete

That's a use case from Florianopolis (capital of SC), in a very well-known street.
If I try to geocode the following address:

Rua João Pio Duarte Silva, 526

It's gonna return an address that is almost 500m far away from the original street number. It happens in the API, but also in the Here Maps, which led me to think the precision in Brazil is not trustable. That's just one scenario, but we've faced similar situations like that.

[image: API result]

Here comes my first question, what's the expected precision of the Here Geocoding API in South Brazil?

## 2) Effect of trailing zeros in the address

Some of the services we use to grab the address return trailing zeros in the house number. We thought it wouldn't be an issue until we faced the following scenario:

[image: Traling zeros]

The only thing that changed in the request is the number from **59** to **00059**.

Here's the difference when displaying the coordinates returned by the Here Geocoding API for the cases above on Google Maps:

[image: Results on Google]

---

**SUMMARY**

I've been using the Here Geocoding API for a while and I feel it's not meeting our expectations, as we require a very precise service so our drivers can be more productive and less exposed to errors. Is there a known issue for Geocoding in Brazil, especially in the South? What's the relevance of the results compared to Google? Anything we could do to overcome those issues above (especially #1)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, thank you for reporting this. We are going to look into it and get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm looking forward to discussing and understanding the limitations of the Here Geolocation API further.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport any news here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try by using mapview if you are specifically in Brazil. Attaching one example reference -

> developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-by-mapview-parameter

For coverage details, refer :

> developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/coverage-geocoder.html

Thanks for reporting the discrepancy. The map however gets loaded with refresh data. Please use 
1) Map creator (locate the poi and make the change, Here team will review and approve it)
2) Use Map Feedback API :

> developer.here.com/documentation/map-feedback/dev_guide/topics/what-is.html